# Express app.get: req.body returns type of value and not the actual value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am quite novice to Express and working on a project. I have 4 radio buttons which represent user answer. I have stored the correct answers in a MongoLabs database which I retrieve and log in the `app.get()` function. I want to check the user answer against those correct answers. However when I log `req.body` I get `[object Object]`

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Online Testing Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="question">
    <p>This is my first question</p>
    <br>
</div>
<div id="answer">
    <form action="/answer" method="get">
        <input id="a" type="radio" name="ans" value="A" >A<br>
        <input id="b" type="radio" name="ans" value="B" >B<br>
        <input id="c" type="radio" name="ans" value="C" >C<br>
        <input id="d" type="radio" name="ans" value="D" >D<br><br><br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./server.js"></script>    

</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
var path = require('path');
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var db;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

mongo.connect('mongodb://deodhar:deodhar@ds015636.mlab.com:15636/correct-answers', function (err, database) {
    if(err){
        return console.log('mongo connect if: ' + err);
    }
    db = database;
    app.listen(8080, function () {
        console.log("Listening on 8080");
    });
});


app.get('/answer', function (req,res) {
    console.log("User answer: " + req.body);
    var cursor = db.collection('answers').find().toArray(function (req,result) {
        console.log(result);
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `GET` requests, there won't be a `req.body`; use `req.query` instead.

Also, if you want to log the contents of an object, don't use string concatenation (using `+`), but pass the object as a separate argument to `console.log` (using `,`):

```
console.log("User answer: ", req.query);
```

Comment: Np. Also this might be helpful to read.  http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query and http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body to see difference.